# @future(limits='2xHeap') not working after Winter '16

Tags: apex

I have a class with @future(limits='2xHeap') and it did work before Winter 16 and stop working now. Did any one experience this ?

```
global class DownloadMyFile implements Schedulable {

    @future(limits='2xHeap')
    private static void callToDownload(){

    }
}
```

This is a feature from Summer 14. 
Release notes : http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_apex_future_methods_enhanced.htm

Comment: How did it "stop working?"

Comment: [Future Methods with Higher Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enhanced_future_overview.htm) notes that this is a pilot feature. Are you a pilot org?

Comment: Schedule it to run in my dev org. Started getting errors. If I edit and hit save, not I'm getting errors. "Error: Compile Error: Unsupported parameters on @future annotation. at line"

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Salesforce confirmed that we were in a pilot and this feature is still in pilot.